# Combining beliefs in probabilistic models

Tags: discrete-data, bayesian-network

I have multiple Bayesian network models, each producing some estimate or inference about a variable $PW_2$, which is given by $P_1(W_2|W_1)$ in one model and $P_2(W_2|W3)$ in the other, but I want just a single distribution over that variable. I need to average them somehow. what is the correct averaging procedure?

The model in question is used to determine the weather for $week_n$ by extrapolating data from $week_{n-1}$ and drawing inferences from $week_{n+1}$. This leaves me with two different beliefs about the distribution $week_n$:

[image]

I know that the correct procedure is to compute the product of corresponding event outcome probabilities in the discrete distributions, and then normalize the resulting distribution by dividing by the sum of all the elements (to make them sum to unity). I am looking for a justification of this procedure.